# How to check if backups are reliable?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, restore, checksum

I generally have to restore databases to different servers after important data imports or other important and delicate database operations.

I need to be sure that my backups up to that point in time or transaction mark are reliable.

I don't have the time and the disk space and to do a [full restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-to-a-marked-transaction-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017) followed by a [dbcc checkdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to completely verify the backup files (including corruption).

[The `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` will check for :](https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/02/restore-verifyonly.html)

1. backup set is present   and header fields of pages
2. Are volumes readable?
3. checksum (if enabled , `BACKUP` by default does not use `CHECKSUM`)
4. destination drive – space check.

I use a lot the following query:

```
--query by Jack Vamvas - any suspect database?
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id),[file_id],page_id,
CASE event_type
   WHEN 1 THEN '823 or 824 or Torn Page'
   WHEN 2 THEN 'Bad Checksum'
   WHEN 3 THEN 'Torn Page'
   WHEN 4 THEN 'Restored'
   WHEN 5 THEN 'Repaired (DBCC)'
   WHEN 7 THEN 'Deallocated (DBCC)'
END,
error_count,
last_update_date
FROM msdb..suspect_pages
```

Other than [restore verify only with checksum](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4454/validate-a-sql-server-backup-can-be-restored/), is there any other way to check if my backups are reliable?

Comment: Sadly, you have to restore it to truly know: ["Shrodinger's Backup - The condition of any backup is unknown until a restore is attempted."](https://twitter.com/nixcraft/status/613636528439345152) - @nixcraft (twitter)

Comment: @JohnEisbrener I would accept this as an answer

Comment: [Andrey's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242985/39083) is frankly the same as mine without the humor, so feel free to mark his as he left it much earlier than I left my comment.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener you are a gentleman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to check if backup is reliable is to restore it.
DBCC Checkdb is not needed after successful restore if you just want to be sure that backup is reliable.